# Best Approach to correct column with different spellings in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with column that has data with spelling errors. 
Like: 
apple, appl, aple
bana, banana, banna
cat, cot, cta

I would like to correct all error spelling to single correct ones. There are thousands of rows.
What would be the best approach to correct this issue where I wouldn't have to update each spelling errors manually?
I have added status iscorrect 'Y' for correct ones.

Comment: Specify the DBMS you are using.

Comment: @ErgiNushi mysql

Comment: I would create a table with 2 columns known_incorrect and correct and use this to update your data.

Comment: I would sort them into alphabetical order. Physically look at the id where the 1st wrong spelling is to the last one. Then update all errors between start id and end id. And move on to the next error

Comment: There is no built-in function that can do spell check, so you should create something yourself.

Comment: How do we know that the error for 'aple' is 'apple', and not, say, 'maple'?

Comment: @Strawberry That part I have done it manually. Like added iscorrect = 'Y' in the spelling I know/feel is correct. Currently, what I have done is grouped the column with count so that unique datas are displayed and manually added iscorrect = 'Y'. So that way, I think, normally there is more probability of correct spellings having larger count.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought, using SOUNDEX. SOUNDEX is really a lousy function, and certainly no panacea, but it *might* reduce a data set comprising thousands of errors to a data set comprising hundreds of errors.

For the rest, we can look at things like Levenshtein distance, but ultimately, you're going to need a manual approach to some extent...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bad_data;

CREATE TABLE bad_data
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,string VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO bad_data (string) VALUES
('apple'), 
('appl'), 
('aple'),
('bana'),
('banana'), 
('banna'),
('cat'),
('cot'), 
('cta');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS good_data;

CREATE TABLE good_data
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,string VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO good_data(string) VALUES
('apple'), 
('banana'), 
('cat');

SELECT * 
  FROM bad_data x 
  JOIN good_data y ON SOUNDEX(x.string) = SOUNDEX(y.string);
+----+--------+------+--------+
| id | string | id   | string |
+----+--------+------+--------+
|  1 | apple  |    1 | apple  |
|  2 | appl   |    1 | apple  |
|  3 | aple   |    1 | apple  |
|  4 | bana   |    2 | banana |
|  5 | banana |    2 | banana |
|  6 | banna  |    2 | banana |
|  7 | cat    |    3 | cat    |
|  8 | cot    |    3 | cat    |
|  9 | cta    |    3 | cat    |
+----+--------+------+--------+
```